# Need help tracing a pseudo-element unselectable in DevTools

Tags: html

I'm working with an external Date Picker React component which, on clicking Submit, outputs a weird popup-type prompt in case the value is invalid.

But I can't zero in on this element or detect it in DevTools, so I have no idea where it's coming from. Trying to select it is impossible, as if it doesn't exist. Also, searching for "Please enter" as text doesn't bring back any results. What kind of technology could this be? Is it not real HTML? I'm not running any 508 tools or plugins.

The second screenshot is when I'm trying to click on that box while it's forced to be open. I can't click on it to select it, even the lower white corner.

NOTE: There is no `required` attribute anywhere. I searched in DevTools. Also, adding `formnovalidate` to the displayed text box does not help.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the standard browser prompt when a field is marked as required. Been around for quite some time

Comment: And how do I disable it? Does it come from an Aria of some kind? First time I'm seeing it!

Comment: There is absolutely no `required` attibute anywhere.

Comment: The issue is on an invalid date, not a required date. Are you still sure it's coming from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `novalidate` inside your form tag

```
<form novalidate>...</form>
```